# Making a Multiindexed Pandas Dataframe Non-Symmetric

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a multi-indexed dataframe which looks roughly like this:

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({('A', 'a'):[1,2,3,4,5], ('A', 'b'):[5,4,3,2,1], ('B', 'a'):[5,2,3,4,1], ('B','b'):[1,4,3,2,5]})
```

```
>>> Output

   A     B   
   a  b  a  b
0  1  5  5  1
1  2  4  2  4
2  3  3  3  3
3  4  2  4  2
4  5  1  1  5
```

In this dataframe, the zero-th row and fifth row are symmetric in the sense that if the entire `A` and `B` columns of the zero-th row are flipped, it becomes identical to the fifth one. Similarly, the second row is symmetric with itself.

I am planning to remove these rows from my original dataframe, thus making it 'non-symmetric'. The specific plans are as follow:

1. If a row with higher index is symmetric with a row with lower index, keep the lower one and remove the higher one. For example, from the above dataframe, keep the zero-th row and remove the fifth row.
2. If a row is symmetric with itself, remove that row. For example, from the above dataframe, remove the second row.

My attempt was to first zip the four lists into a tuple list, remove the symmetric tuples by a simple `if`-statement, unzip them, and merge them back into a dataframe. However, this turned out to be inefficient, making it unscalable for large dataframes.

How can I achieve this in an efficient manner? I guess utilizing several built-in `pandas` methods is necessary, but it seems quite complicated.

Comment: So should everything except the first row get removed from your sample data?

Comment: @thushv89 No, additionally the first and third (note that I am counting from zero-th row) stays as is; they are not symmetric with any rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namudon'tdie,

Try this solution:

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({('A', 'a'):[1,2,3,4,5], ('A', 'b'):[5,4,3,2,1], ('B', 'a'):[5,2,3,4,1], ('B','b'):[1,4,3,2,5]})

test['idx'] = test.index * 2  # adding auxiliary column 'idx' (all even)

test2 = test.iloc[:, [2,3,0,1,4]]   # creating flipped DF
test2.columns = test.columns  # fixing column names
test2['idx'] = test2.index * 2 + 1  # for flipped DF column 'idx' is all odd

df = pd.concat([test, test2])
df = df.sort_values (by='idx')
df = df.set_index('idx')
print(df)

     A     B   
     a  b  a  b
idx            
0    1  5  5  1
1    5  1  1  5
2    2  4  2  4
3    2  4  2  4
4    3  3  3  3
5    3  3  3  3
6    4  2  4  2
7    4  2  4  2
8    5  1  1  5
9    1  5  5  1

df = df.drop_duplicates()  # remove rows with duplicates 
df = df[df.index%2 == 0]  # remove rows with odd idx (flipped)
df = df.reset_index()[['A', 'B']] 
print(df)

   A     B   
   a  b  a  b
0  1  5  5  1
1  2  4  2  4
2  3  3  3  3
3  4  2  4  2
```

The idea is to create flipped rows with odd indexes, so that they will be placed under their original rows after reindexing. Then delete duplicates, keeping rows with lower indices. For cleanup simply delete remaining rows with odd indices.

Note that row `[3,3,3,3]` stayed. There should be a separate filter to take care of self-symmetric rows. Since your definition of self-symmetric is unclear (other rows have certain degree of symmetry too), I leave this part to you. Should be straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it as soon as possible.

Comment: Please write your result here. accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: Sorry I was late; I really like the code. The logic behind here is to interleave flipped rows between original rows and remove duplicated rows; hence removing the symmetric rows in the original frame. After that is done, we un-interleave the inserted rows. As for the self-symmetric rows, I would just select rows where `A` and `B` column values are all equal to each other. I accepted and upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thanks!
Just note that "A equals B" condition is also true for row [2 4 2 4]. It was one of the reasons I stumbled with self-symmetric rows...